# How to Hide TextBox without using Visibility:none

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Goal:
Hide the textbox () without using css's "visibility:none;" and it should not take any white space row.

Problem:
Don't know any good solution to it.

Info:
*The code works only for EE and Chrome.
*Tried display: none, visibility: none and visibility: hidden but don't work to fullfill the goal.

"https://jsfiddle.net/yszq53jm/16/"

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) {
  var test = document.querySelector('.lame');
  var bkp = test.value;
    
  test.select();
  document.execCommand('cut');
  test.value = bkp;
});
```

```css
.lame {
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}

textarea:not(.lame) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p style="cursor: pointer;">
    link
</p>
<textarea class="lame">
<table>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
</tr>
</table>
</textarea>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Uh...when you say `visibility: none`, do you mean `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`? I think you may have accidentally mixed them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that your intention is to mimic `display: none`(element not visible, no space reserved for it in the layout), you can try setting the element height to 0 and removing all padding/borders from it. So you could change your CSS for `.lame` to this:

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) {
  var test = document.querySelector('.lame');
  var bkp = test.value;
    
  test.select();
  document.execCommand('cut');
  test.value = bkp;
});
```

```css
.lame {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    resize: none;
}
textarea:not(.lame) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p style="cursor: pointer;">link</p>
<textarea class="lame">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** I've now modified the CSS so the content is still focusable, since it cannot properly select the content when height is 0.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, I guess your primary question here is actually why your JavaScript doesn't seem to do what you want it to do?

Comment: @HelloWorld On that note...what exactly do you intend/expect your JavaScript to do?

Comment: @HelloWorld All right, I understand what you mean now. I've edited the answer to take into account the issue my original solution had.

Comment: It works for IE and does it work when you use Chrome?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 44.0.2403.157 (I was doing my testing mostly in this browser).

Comment: It still works when you use the code that you have uploaded to the cod snippet?

Comment: Yeah, when I try it with "Run code snippet". Not working for you?

Comment: It is not working in my client computer. Tomorrow, I gonna test another computer. The code works well for IE but not Chrome in my client computer.

Comment: I see. Perhaps there are compatibility problems with `execCommand()`, since that is still currently in the process of being adopted across major browsers? Anyways, hopefully we can pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: I tried another computer and it works perfectly for the latest version of IE and Chrome. Thanks for your help!